# Visual Studio reference separate git project

Tags: c#, git

## Example

- C# Project A is stored in *internal* Git Repository A
- C# Project B is stored in *internal* Git Repository B but references Project A

## Question

What is a simple way for Project B to reference a Project A?

## Options considered

- Install, configure, and deploy internal NuGet server
- Check Project A's dll into git and use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) since it has the [ability](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies) to add a dependency directly to a git url (including version)
- Use git submodule
- Use git subtree
- Copy Project A's dll manually into Project B

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest Nuget, but you don't need a server. Nuget can work from a simple local folder. Setting it up takes one minute.
Set up a git repo for the packages and clone it on your machines. In VS, Tools->Options->Nuget, configure a new package repository pointing to your local folder.